# Assistance with SQL Query (Windowing Functions)

Tags: sql, grouping

```
Houston Apartment         Order 1
Houston Apartment            Order 5
Houston TownHouse   Order 3
Houston TownHouse   Order 4
Austin  Condo   
Dallas  MultiFamily Order 2
```

All,

I have a result set like the one above.
Using the familiar Customer -> Orders schema as an example,
The first two columns (e.g. Houston, Apartment) come from category1 and category2 fields on the Customer Table.
The third column comes from the Orders Table and will represent the Primary Key of the table.  The values in this column were deliberately listed out of order (1...5...3) to show that I cannot guarantee the order the values.

What I want is to have a column that adds a Rank or Row_number (or calculation?) that numbers each combination of Category 1 and 2:

```
1   Houston Apartment   Order 1
1   Houston Apartment   Order 5
2   Houston TownHouse            Order 3
2   Houston TownHouse   Order 4
3   Austin  Condo   
4   Dallas  MultiFamily Order 2
```

So, Houston-Aparment is 1, Houston-TownHouse is 2, etc...

I would like to avoid *any* sub/nested queries if possible.

Please note:
The values in the example or just sample data.  The real data is not based on a Customer/orders so I respectfully and humbly ask that you please not chastise me for having Cities and Apartment types as categories, etc (I would put these in separate domain tables in this instance) or suggest a change of schema

Can anyone help please?!

Steve

Comment: which rdbms are you using? @andomar makes a good point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the results that you show, I think you want:

```
select dense_rank() over (order by Category1, Category2) as rankorder, *
from Customers c join
     Orders o
     on o.CustomerID = c.CustomerID
```

You seem to be adding an index based only on the first two categories, and never starting over again (the partition is used to start counting over again).  You have ties with no gaps (1, 1, 2 . . .).  For this case, you want dense_rank().  If you had ties with gaps (1, 1, 3 . . .), you would use rank().  If you just wanted the ordering (1, 2, 3) you would use row_number().

Comment: Thank you so much.  I will try this tonight but just knowing of yet another option to try is exciting.  I will update select this as the answer if it works.  THANKS AGAIN!

Comment: Dense_Rank() was the answer to my frustration and prayers.  I still needed to use Partition By for my specific requirements, but this is the answer that allowed me to fix my problem.  I had to use this in a Matrix SSRS report, and this allowed me to present a nice, clean table with blank lines removed.  (The blank lines were caused by the gap in the index that Rank() created.)

Answer (score 0):

If your database supports windowing functions, you could use `row_number()`:

```
select  row_number() over (partition by Category1, Category2 order by CustomerID)
from    Customers c
join    Orders o
on      o.CustomerID = c.CustomerID
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should do:

```
create table Data
(
    city varchar(50),
    propertyType varchar(50),
    anOrder int
)
insert into Data select 'Houston', 'Apartment', 1
insert into Data select 'Houston', 'Apartment', 5
insert into Data select 'Houston', 'TownHouse', 3
insert into Data select 'Houston', 'TownHouse', 4
insert into Data select 'Austin', 'Condo', 1
insert into Data select 'Dallas', 'MultiFamily', 2

select city, propertyType, RANK() OVER 
    (PARTITION BY Data.city ORDER BY Data.city,Data.propertyType DESC) AS Rank 
from Data
group by city, propertyType
```